# mysql_fetch_array only returns first column

Tags: php, mysql

I really, really need help with the following code. I just can't figure out why it's not working.

There is a MySQL Table that I need to query and I simply need to return one row for a specific ID. However mysql_fetch_array only returns the first column from that table - and I'm dying from frustration...

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM sqlInformationen WHERE ID = 2"; 

$sqlConn = mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die ("Fehler bei der Verbindungsaufnahme."); 

$result = mysql_query($sqlCommand); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  

echo $row['infTitel'];
```

The database contains fields "ID", "infTitel", "infZusammenfassung", etc. However only echo $row['ID'] returns a value.

Would greatly appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($row);` ?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @raina77ow print_r($row) doesn't return anything, echo $row only returns "Array"

Comment: @Matthias Weird. Ok, let's use `var_dump($row)` instead (right before `echo $row['infTitel']` line).

Comment: @raina77ow same as print_r - doesn't return anything. however when I query a different table I get a result of what's in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

to get associative array as result.

`mysql_fetch_array($result)` also returns both numeric indexes and associative indexes, but I am not sure since which version.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch Row gets one row at a time, you should pop it into a while loop like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['infTitel'];
    echo $row['col2'];
    echo $row['col3'];
}
```

If you are echoing the contents of the row that you selected with a `select *` and you are getting no value, it likely means that the column is empty for that row.

If you are using fetch_array it should return both column names and indexes. Try this to see if you get your data:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    for($i=0; $i<count($row);, $i++)
    {
        echo $row[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

If this is showing you the data you expect (empty or null rows should return empty from memory) then it is possible a case sensitivity issue with your `$row['Colname']` syntax?

Comment: *I simply need to return one row for a specific ID*

Comment: Using mysql_fetch_assoc() would be better, considering OP is looking to use an assoc array. mysql_fetch_array returns both rows and assoc.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response! this works fine for returning $row['ID'] - however I don't get any values for $row['infTitel']

Comment: @Matthias Are you utterly certain you have the column names correct in the `$row['columnName']` part of your code?

Comment: @Fluffeh - yes, i've double checked using the terminal.

Comment: @Fluffeh the console returns "1" for the select count(*) statement. I don't get any echo on the page when looping through the results.

Comment: @Matthias Okay, I am running out of ideas, but can you show me the output if you run your select statement from a console? Perhaps it is some funky encoding issue with characters? You got no results when you added the `for...` loop? Nothing?

Answer (score 2):

After $result = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: This code is a bit odd. You would only print the very last result of the query.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forget to add [] to store $row in array. Thank You.